# How does dark matter decrease predict CMB anystropies?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, cosmic-microwave-background

Measured matter overdensities today are $\delta_{0m}=\frac{\Delta \rho_m}{\rho_m}\geq 1$, which means that at the time of photon decoupling, they must have been $\delta_{dec,m}\geq 10^{-3}$. 
But this would mean that (assuming adiabatic perturbations), the CMB temperature anysotropies would be $\frac{\Delta T}{T} \gtrsim 10^{-3}$, which contradicts the observed value $\frac{\Delta T}{T} \lesssim 10^{-5}$.

How does dark matter solve this issue? This derivation only assumes that $\ddot \delta_m + 2H\dot \delta_m  = 4\pi G\rho_m \delta_m$ and that we can relate matter and radiation densities through $\Delta \rho_m/\rho_m =3/4 \Delta \rho_r/\delta \rho_r$.

How could we predict an upper bound of $\frac{\Delta T}{T}$?